# Add a button and call corresponding function in asp page

Tags: asp-classic

I want to add a button to an asp page. 
The scenario is:

If name returned from above function = 'abc'
   Then show button 
   on button click call function 'A'
Else
End if

Can anyone help me in adding this button and calling the function in the code. I have least knowledge of asp .

Comment: Also i have no idea where to add this server side and client side code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make two classic asp files called submission.asp and process_submission.asp (you can make one file, but I'll use two in this example).  In submission.asp, call your GetName() function and show the button if GetName() is "abc".  If the user clicks your submit button, the request is sent to the process_submission.asp file.  In that file, make a function called "CallFunctionA" and execute that function if the Request("Action") = "CallFunctionA".

**submission.asp:**

```
<form name="frmSubmissionForm" action="process_submission.asp">
<%

Dim FunctionResult
FunctionResult = GetName()

if FunctionResult = "abc" then
    %>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="CallFunctionA" />
    <%

end if

' Sample Function
Function GetName()
    GetName = "abc"
End Function

%>
</form>
```

**process_submission.asp:**

```
<%

Dim Result

if Request("Action") = "CallFunctionA" then
    Result = CallFuctionA()
end if

Response.Write Result

' Sample Function
Function CallFuctionA()
    CallFuctionA = "Hello World"
End Function

%>
```